# How to check that the argument to a bash script are "flags"

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to ensure that the given arguments are flags, by which I mean `-x` where `x` is some character or sequence of.

I have tried to do this with the following:

```sh
if [[ "$(echo '$1' | sed 's/[^-]//g')" -ne "-" ]];
then
  echo "$usage"
  exit
fi
```

Where my reasoning is that if `-` is not present when other characters are stripped it's not a flag.

This doesn't work though, and is obviously flimsy, but I don't know how to do this correctly.

```sh
# valid
script.sh -asdf
# invalid
script.sh sdf
```

Comment: Tag for bash _or_ zsh, not both in the same question. They're very different, mutually-incompatible shells.

Comment: @baxx : Your question sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Are you really interested only if some of the arguments are like flags, or do you want to actually process these flags and take actions according to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way to make sure `$1` is starting with `-`:

```
if [[ "${1?}" != -* ]]; then
   echo "$usage"
   exit 1
fi
```

`${1?}` will fail the script if `$1` is not available.

Comment: thanks - I like that it will fail, but would also like for usage to be output in the case of failure, perhaps I should add an additional if to check that some parameters are input, though it seems as though there should be a way to catch that here.

Comment: I can adapt from here it's ok, thanks. What I meant was if $1 was empty - but i think it's a separate question

Comment: Actually $1 empty check is already happening by placing a ? In ${1?}

Comment: @anubhava : The `?` aborts the script with an error message, if the parameter is empty. So it is "check+abort".